# Is it possible to start Firefox via PythonSelenium in a way that the menu bar is displayed from the beginning?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

I am (as a newbie) experimenting with Python and Selenium.
I have managed to write a script that starts Firefox via Selenium and logs into the websites I need for work using my IDs and passwords:

```
usr='xxx'
pwd='xxx'

# firefox öffnen und seite öffnen
driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.site-online.de')

#username usr eintragen
username_box=driver.find_element_by_id('username')
username_box.send_keys(usr)

#pw pwd1 eintragen
pwd_box=driver.find_element_by_id('passwd')
pwd_box.send_keys(pwd)
```

Great so far. However I note that the Firefox browser does not initially display the Menu Bar at the top (File, Edit, View...).

I have found out that it can be activated by a right click in the top region of the browser. **However, is there a way to activate the menu bar directly by the Python script?**

Thank you for any answer.
TACologne